# 3rd party .jar includes with Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, classpath

I am writing a Google App Engine app using Java that uses 3rd party libraries. I am getting a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" when running the app when it hits the line with references to the 3rd party library. This app works when creating a normal servlet, so I am pretty sure the code is correct.

I am developing in Eclipse.

Does the app engine not allow 3rd party libraries?

Do I need to configure the class path differently?

HELP!!

Comment: From my experience, if you're getting it to compile, it's probably not your class path.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the 3rd-party library uses things that aren't allowed by the GAE sandbox environment, it may not work even if you do manage to get it to find the class definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Please see if the library you are using [will play in the google app engine or not?](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava)
This link lists most third party libraries/frameworks and the issues that occur when you use different versions of them with GAE and also possible solutions if any.

The ClassNotFoundError is seen in a some instances with some libraries with GAE. for [example](http://www.google-app-engine.com/blog/post/Spring-security-fix-for-google-app-engine.aspx) spring-security etc.

Comment: Thank you @Diederik. Fixed the link. The original link now seems to be moved here.

Answer (score 3):

If using Eclipse, You need to copy the required jar(s) to the /WEB-INF/lib folder manually.

Comment: Really? This is somewhat surprising and disappointing. I am starting with Eclipse and Java after spending much time on Visual Studio. I was such a breeze just reference a DLL and VS would take care copying it to output dir.

Comment: @Schultz9999 Just use Maven